# Enable session state

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, webforms

I'm using C# asp.net. I have deployed my site to Sharepoint 2010 and after deployment I get an error that says enable session state. I managed to solve this error by adding the following code to web.config file:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="Session" />
        <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

and I added this to the page directive:

```
enableSessionState="true"
```

Is there a way to add it in the master page? 
I tried adding `enableSessionState="true"` but I get this error: `Error 10  Error parsing attribute 'enablesessionstate': Type 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not have a public property named 'enablesessionstate'` 
am I doing it wrong? if so, what is the correct way to enable session state in master page?

Comment: I think you should edit to explain what you're trying to do more. Enabling session state on the master page doesn't really make much sense. You can talk about tracking session state with a particular web request or enabling it in the asp.net application. I don't think talking about session state in the layout means anything though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use the `enableSessionState` attribute of the `Page` directive to manipulate session. You use the `sessionState` element (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx) and only use the pages's one to disable session for a specific Page.

And I'm also not sure why you are disabling the session by removing the Session module (I'm not even sure this will work). You would normallly do it like this:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```